# Extraction of unit of measure using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to user the following regular expression to extract measurement values from sizes stated in text such as:

```
23 x 54mm
23 cm by 56cm
25 cm
4mm
5 centimeters
etc.
```

and have gotten this far with the expression but am returning pattern error:

```
"([\- ](mm|cm|millimeter(s)?|centimeter(s)?)(?![a-z/]))" 
/
gm
All the errors detected are listed below, from left to right, as they appear in the pattern.
/ An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash (\)
```

Any suggestions on corrections?

Comment: Missing delimiters `/` at the start and end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping There you can read about escaping

`([\- ](mm|cm|millimeter(s)?|centimeter(s)?)(?![a-z\/]))` - right way to write it